# Jasmin Mock $http (then, catch)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Ive been using the following code for ages to test the following code example.

```
function loadAccounts() {
  return AccountCaller.loadAccounts()
  .then(function(response){
    AccountsModel.accounts = response.accounts;
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    ErrorHandler.raise(error);
  });
}

var spy= spyOn(mock, 'loadAccounts').andCallFake(function () {
        return {
            then: function (callback) {
                return callback(response);
            }
        };
    });
```

The above code works fine on the '.then' but i recently introduced the '.catch' and now my tests fails 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined'.

Any ideas on how i can deal with the '.catch' element, if i remove it then the code test runs fine !!!

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your spy of `then` you have `return callback(response);`, but your callback does not return anything, which is why you get the `undefined` in your error. The thing you're returning will need to at least have a `catch` method of some kind attached to it. You can test that with something like this:

```
var spy= spyOn(mock, 'loadAccounts').andCallFake(function () {
    return {
        then: function (callback) {
            callback(response);
            return {catch: function() {}};
        }
    };
});
```

^^ This isn't necessarily how I'd do that, but it should get you moving in the right direction. Consider returning the result of `callback(response)` wrapped in a `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks I now get 'TypeError: AccountCaller.loadAccounts(...).then(...).then is not a function'. response by the way is set as response = {}; with some mock accounts data